# How to require the same parameter type between scala traits?

Tags: scala

I am working on a web server to process a registration form and save it to a datastore. I want this to be a library and work with different instances of registration forms.

I have the following:

```
trait RegistrationForm

case class SimpleRegistrationForm(name: String,
                                  email: String,
                                  username: String,
                                  password: String) extends RegistrationForm
```

I want any subclass of `RegistrationForm` to be acceptable to my server.

I have the following traits:

```
/**
  * Interface for saving to a datastore
  */
trait RegistrationDataStore[T <: RegistrationForm] {
  def save(form: T): Either[DataStoreException, String]
}


/**
  * Trait to handle the form. 
  */
trait RegistrationService[T <: RegistrationForm] {
  def handleForm(form: T): Either[AkkaHttpExtensionsException, String]
}
```

And an implementation:

```
class RegistrationServiceImpl[T <: RegistrationForm](
    registrationDataStore: RegistrationDataStore[T])
  extends RegistrationService[T] {

  def handleForm(form: T): Either[AkkaHttpExtensionsException, String] = {

    registrationDataStore.save(form)
  }
```

My server basically looks like this:

```
object Server {
      ...
      val registrationService = new RegistrationServiceImpl[SimpleRegistrationForm](
new RegistrationMockDataStore[SimpleRegistrationForm]())
      ...
}
```

How can I require that the same form subclass is passed as type parameters to implementations of both `RegistrationService` and `RegistrationDataStore`? At the moment, won't they both accept independent subclasses of `RegistrationForm` (I can't test because this doesn't yet compile)? E.g. will the following be valid, and if so, how can I prevent it?

```
val registrationService = new RegistrationServiceImpl[SimpleRegistrationForm](
  new RegistrationMockDataStore[SomeOtherRegistrationForm]())
```

How can I force the compiler to make sure they are the **same** subclass of `RegistrationForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't be valid. Your constructor parameter is `registrationDataStore: RegistrationDataStore[T]`, so when you write `new RegistrationServiceImpl[SimpleRegistrationForm](something)`, `something` must be a `RegistrationDataStore[SimpleRegistrationForm]`.